# How can I upload a file in JSP without using two JSP files?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web, project

[I'm trying to upload file using "Upload FIle" label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezF0P.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @n-s. Please place any relevant code in your question, instead of a link to a picture of the code.

Comment: Easy, because the URL of the form POST should *not* be to a JSP, but to a Servlet (or request handler if you're using some other framework). You use a JSP to render HTML, i.e. to show the form, then a Servlet to handle the POST request, which redirects back to the form (or somewhere else) when the upload has completed processing.

Answer (score 0):

Solo JSP, file = upload.jsp

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file name=file1>
<input type=submit>
</form>

<%
  if (request.getContentType()==null) return;
  <... your upload code, whether this is Apache Commons or straight JSP...>
%>
<% out.println("File has been uploaded."); %>
```